# Social leper versus social leopard

Tags: meaning

Someone explained to me that [social leopard](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/1066/leopard/) refers to someone who is social, but I think it actually means "social leper". Who is right? Thank you!

Comment: A social leper probably isn't social though.

Comment: Social leopards don't exist , never have so far. Something like the kids having a 'gift vulture' for a present.

Comment: @Tim [Social leopards _do_ exist](https://i0.wp.com/www.environewsnigeria.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/snow-leopards.jpg?ssl=1) :-)

Comment: @TripeHound - not quite tongue-in-cheek...

Comment: Seeing as that site that you link to is a satirical site, relating to [Mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) (eggcorn => acorn), *social leopard* is quite clearly a joke...

Comment: @Greenonline it's not satirical - it's a *sincere* effort to catalogue [non-standard reshapings](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/about/) encountered in the wild.

Comment: [Don't be a social leopard; when all is set and done, making linguistic mistakes because you have heard a phrase incorrectly is very common.](https://www.facebook.com/theguardian/posts/dont-be-a-social-leopard-when-all-is-set-and-done-making-linguistic-mistakes-bec/10152710360901323/)

Comment: @AakashM So, it’s on the list somewhere. But can the *social leopard* change its spot?

Comment: "Social Leopard" is a misspelling of "social leper".  The site that you link to is just a collection of humorous misspellings like this.

Comment: A leopard cannot change his [shorts](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/A_leopard_can%27t_change_his_shorts)

Comment: @TripeHound - looks like the cub is *not* happy about getting a bath from mom..!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I thought it was *social butterfly*. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_butterfly):

> A social butterfly is a slang term for a person who is socially dynamic, networking, charismatic, and personally gregarious.

---

Whereas a *social leper* can be broken down to *social* and *leper*.

According to [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leper) a *leper* is someone affected with leprosy. Leprosy is a serious, contagious and fatal disease caused by a mycobacterium leprae.

A *leper* is also defined as *a person shunned for moral or social reasons* by [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leper). So it would make sense in a social context that lepers will always be avoided.

Therefore, a *social leper* would be someone that is deliberately avoided.

---

The term "social leopard" isn't found anywhere, can be assumed to be a mis-hearing for *social leper*.

Comment: You haven't addressed the 'social leopard' aspect of the question. Even a 'this isn't found anywhere so I assume they meant social leper' would do.

Comment: @marcellothearcane edited.

Comment: Also, see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leper

Answer (score 61):

A "leper" is someone who has leprosy. Now leprosy is very rare in the developed world, and can be cured easily. In fact, leprosy isn't even a very contagious disease.

But in the past, people were terrified of it. Quarantine was about the only effective medical technique they had (removing blood by cutting and leeches wasn't as helpful as you'd think). So if you saw someone with leprosy, you'd run like hell, lest you catch it yourself.

So lepers were avoided and shunned. Sent off to "leper colonies" to live, or die, away from everyone else.

So you can guess from this, a "social leper" is someone who isn't popular! There's an implication that if you hung around with them, you'd catch "social leprosy" too and would also start being avoided by friends. This can be for what's considered a good reason among those people, or it can be for bad reasons. Sometimes doing (or being) a particular thing can make you a social leper. Sometimes it's just falling out with the wrong person.

"Social leopard" is just a mis-hearing.

Comment: It's worth a mention that "social leopard" is a mondegreen or an eggcorn.

Comment: *"Easily cured"* - Sure, if that's how you want to describe treatment that takes 6 to 24 months and doesn't reverse any existing nerve damage or disfigurement, etc. (But yes, leprosy is certainly less scary than it was before effective treatments existed.)

Comment: Don't Mondegreens have to be musical in nature?

Comment: Oh okay. I actually thought it was a simple matter of antibiotics. And yes the existing nerve damage is permanent since, AIUI, they're destroyed. That's where the legendary "bits of your body falling off" comes from. Nerves die, in some part of the body. It goes numb. So when it's damaged, the person doesn't feel it. This can lead to infection, and so your finger / nose / whatever, dies and rots off. That's as I understand it. People must have seen lepers with pieces missing and assumed leprosy itself makes bits of you fall off. Nowadays, though, that's rare in developed countries.

Comment: It wouldn't be the only metaphor to survive a change in technology that made its literal sense obsolete.

Comment: @Greenaum  No, Mondegreens can happen anywhere.  There are probably a disproportionately large number of them in music lyrics ("Excuse me while I kiss this guy", "The girl with Colitis goes by", etc.) as well as deliberate constructs like "Mairzy Dotes", but that doesn't preclude non-musical Mondegreen sightings.

Comment: The term *mondegreen* was originally coined in reference to misheard lines in a spoken ballad or poem, and has since been widely applied to misheard song lyrics too. I don't think it applies to misheard phrases more generally, so I wouldn't call "social leopard" a mondegreen, but it seems the dictionary disagrees with me about that.

Comment: Something about "they took the lord and laid him on the green", became "took the Lord and Lady Mondegreen". From songs, yes, that's what I always thought it meant. Came to prominence on the Internet in the 1990s, but I dunno if it's earlier than that.

Comment: “(removing blood by cutting and leeches wasn’t as helpful as you’d think)” — Well, _I think_ it would be utterly useless in curing any medical problems in any way, and would likely just lead to some sort of anaemia or something, which would only exacerbate any issues. I’d love to know what it actually did, if it’s not even as ‘helpful’ as that!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - FINE! The next time *you* get sick *you* can go see some traveling medical quack for a potion that's mostly ALCOHOL with some poisons mixed in for flavor! Meanwhile, us SMART people will go to a barber-chirurgeon and have leeches suck the bad humours out! IF IT WAS GOOD ENOUGH FOR ARISTOTLE IT'S GOOD ENOUGH FOR ME!!!!! (Put another way - it kept the sick people exhausted and docile so that they'd die quietly without too much fuss and bother. I guess the motto of the barber-chirurgeons was, "If you can't do anything useful, you can at least give 'em a shave"). :-)

Comment: @Greenaum - *Mondegreen* [1] was coined in 1954, inspired by the line you’ve mentioned, from the "Scottish ballad *The Bonny Earl o Moray*"[2]. Evidently, I acquired the term from an unreliable source, because I thought it was *mondegren* (which appears in Google searches but not in the Ngram Viewer).


  [1]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mondegreen
  [2]: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-mondegreen-1691401